# Is it possible to define motion scene transitions without constrainSetStart?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I struggle with creating more universal motion layout scenes. Every tutorial example I have seen so far considers using `app:constraintSetStart="@+id/constraintSet1"
 app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/constraintSet2"`

Here is my motion scene xml, maybe some attributes are wrongly declared.

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition android:id="@+id/title1_motion"
        app:duration="1000"
            app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/title1_down">

        <onClick
            app:clickAction="toggle"
            app:targetId="@id/title1_down" />

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/title1_down">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/textView1">
            <Layout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
            <Transform android:translationY="50dp" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

What I achieved for now is a smiple mechanism which tracks current `constraintSetId` with `MotionLayout.TransitionListener`. Based on the last motion layout transition it is possible to use 
`transitionToState(int id)` followed by `transitionToEnd()` with the ID from transition listener.

The effect of transitioning from any constraintSet is achieved. Is doing this programmatically the only possible way?